# Resetting a Device in Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, ios5, deployment, xcode4.4, xcode-organizer

I've made many mistakes in the process of adding a device to the organizer to deploy to it.

I want to completely start over, but every time I delete the device, unplug it from my computer, and re-add it, it already recognizes it, meaning the "Use for development" option is unavailable, and the error "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" always pops up.

How do I just start from scratch??

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

And this is very urgent, thanks!

UPDATE:: Have these errors constantly pop up -

1. Provisioning Profiles - VAlid Signing identity not found

2.Unable to codesign using identities in this team: no provate keys available

3.Software version - XCode cannot find the software image to install this version (5.1.1 (9B206) )

Comment: On the device, go to "Settings", "General", and removing the provisioning profile.

Comment: there is no option for that. what do you mean?

Comment: If a device has been set up for Development, it should have a provisioning profile. It's called "Profile" and it will be just above "Reset".

Comment: ok i did that but it still doesnt reset completely. I want it to give me the original option of "Use for development"

Comment: ok nvm i had to ignore the device to get that option but its still not working, it should also prompt me for a username and password, how do i get that prompt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can start from scratch by going to "Keychain Access." Go to passwords, and delete your appleID. Then, it will prompt you for your apple ID again.

To resolve the specified issues, you need a development certificate, which will automatically be requested only if you login using your account. Then the administrator will log in to his account and approve your request. Once the certificate is created, it will still not work.

You need to download both the certificate to add to your certificates in keychains, and also the provisioning profile.